"UPI" integration problem in Android Java
when select paytm and BHIM cannot open application android java
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=upi://pay?pa=recipient-vpa@upi&pn=RecipientName&mc=0000&tid=0000000000&tr=orderid123&tn=TestTransaction&am=10&cu=INR pkg=net.one97.paytm }

This error could occur if the intent is not registered, Intents might be only active after activation of UPI.
I would recommned you to complete activation of UPI on BHIM app and try.

Activation completed in BHIM app
